# A global variable becomes nil when called from another package in Golang

Tags: go, testing

repo/common/logger.go

```
package common
var once sync.Once
var Logger *logrus.Logger
func InitLogger() {
   once.Do(func() {
        Logger = logrus.New()
        Logger.Out = filename // file opened and *file assigned here for logging
    })

    return Logger
}
```

repo/setup_test.go

```
package main
func setUp() {
    common.InitLogger()
    fmt.Println(common.Logger) // prints some pointer related things which means logger is initialized
}
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    fmt.Println("Starting Test...")
    setUp()
    code := m.Run()
    common.APILog.Println("Finishing Main...")
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

repo/vehicle/brand/maruti/car/mycar_test.go

```
package car
func TestMyFunc(t *testing.T) {
    **t.Log(common.Logger)               // When i run go test ./... this Prints nil , Why ?**
    // Doing some tests
}
```

Due to this common.Logger.Println("some data") is giving nil pointer error everywhere
As per my understanding once Logger is initialized it should be available as it is a global variable. I am definitely missing something subtle here.
Please help

Comment: I recommend to instantiate logger once instead and then passing it down as dependency via dependency injection. Your code organization is not testable from design, probably will be good for you to be informed about alternative philosophy for another very popular logger https://github.com/uber-go/zap/issues/717#issuecomment-496640441 With this approach and zaptest package you can achieve awesome experience

Comment: When you run `go test` on package car it tests package car only. TestMain is _never_ run.

Comment: @Olegs. Thanks for the response and will check out uber-go/zap as well

Comment: @Volker. So when i run go test ./... It is running go test seperately for all packages so either every package should have a TestMain or as -Olegs said I can pass the logger as a dependency. Am I understanding it correctly ?

Comment: @AmanPatel. Yes, each package is tested in isolation. No, only you should not use TestMain for such purpose. Maybe, I didn't study Olegs answer in detail. Keep it simple. Have a `func init()` in car_test.go which calls common.Logger().

Comment: @Volker. Yes did that. Its works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Each package is tested independently. The tests for `main` have a `TestMain` that calls `setUp`. The tests for `car` do not, so the variable is uninitialized when that package is being tested.

Comment: Got it , thanks @Adrian. So it is like one program ran and tested for package main and stopped.Then another program ran and started testing for car and didnt find the variable as it was never initialized in this context

Comment: That's correct. Each package is tested completely in isolation.